# Microsoft Graph SPA Tutorial not working for messages

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am attempting to create a proof of concept for an SPA which will allow end users (who have an office365 account) to sign in and view their office365 emails.
However, I have two issues when testing with this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa

1. When I sign in with my personal 365 account, sign in works but I get a 401 unauthorized response when requesting this endpoint "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages".
   Compared with when I request the basic tutorial "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me" endpoint I get 200 and the correct data.
2. When I log in with my work 365 account, sign in is rejected in the sign in popup...
   "User account 'redacted' from identity provider 'redacted' does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application 'redacted'(redacted) in that tenant.
   The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account."

I've tested both my personal and work accounts here and they both work fine: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

I'm therefore concerned I haven't correctly modified this tutorial or my app registration, as I don't want to manually added individual users to my tenancy (if that is even a thing) - I have assumed anyone with a valid o365 login will eventually be able to use my spa to read their own emails.

To test the messages endpoint I made these changes to the tutorial code:

- added a msalConfig.auth.redirectUri to match the one in my App registration
- changed graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint from "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me" and "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages"
- changed requestObj.scopes from ["user.read"] to ["user.read", "mail.read"]

I have made these changes to my App registration:

1. App registrations > My App > Authentication

   - Redirect URIs > added URIs for local and production
   - Implicit Grant > checked Access tokens and ID tokens
   - Supported account types > I have tried this with all 3 settings, currently set to "Accounts in any organizational directory"
2. Certificates & secrets > none
3. API permissions > this initially was only set to defalt "User.Read". Now includes "Mail.Read" also type Delegated and Granted for Default Directory
4. Expose an API > none
5. Owners > default my user set as type member
6. Roles and Administrators > none
7. Manifest > I manually set these two values

   - "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2
   - "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"

I've searched stackoverflow, MS tutorials, blogs and I'm going round in circles - I don't know what else to try - does anyone have any advice for what other code or app registration config settings I might need to make to get what I thought would be a simple POC up and running?

Comment: what is the actual error you are getting here from the SDK?
if you update to Microsoft.Graph.Core 1.18 you can get at at the service exceptions.

            try
            {
                var user = await graphClient.Me
                       .Request(headerOptions)
                       .GetAsync();
            }catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.RawResponseBody);
            }